# How to do single page selection?

Tags: vuejs2, datatables

I place the data in the jQuery DataTables Library
A built-in display of several data on one page (there are four choices of 10, 25, 50, and 100 pages).

I have a checkbox for each item of data.
How to select a single page all checkbox?

At the beginning, I just want to press the next page to select all the checkboxes on the entire page, but the number of strokes per page can be adjusted (10, 25, 50, 100), so it cannot be completed.

I use Vue2 to do select all.

I am looking to check all checkboxes on a single page

Even if I select the next page and adjust the number of strokes to 50, I can still select 50 strokes on this page

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Do you want to select all checkboxes on a page, then open page 2 and select all checkboxes on that page as well?

Comment: I have found that the dataTable library will directly display the data of the second page when the second page is clicked, and the screen will not be refreshed. What I want to do is to select all 1-25 pens on the first page; when I cut to the second page 26-50 pens to select all; on the third page 51-75 to select all...

Comment: The premise is that I have a menu in the upper left corner, and only 25 pens are displayed on a single page.
If I change it to 10 strokes per page
Then select all 1-10 on the first page
When switching to the second page, select all 11-20...

Comment: Other pages don't exist in the DOM. DataTables regenerates the table rows each time you switch to another page. If you want to do something with rows from multiple pages then you'll probably need to save the IDs (or some other unique reference to the row data) in a JavaScript array and deal with it that way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I am trying to choose to fetch tr only to find that I can't catch the element. What is the point of saving the Id in the array? can you give an example

Comment: In addition, if the id is really obtained successfully, there is another problem that when you display multiple quantities on a single page in the upper left corner, this will change the number of selections on a single page. This part of the datatable does not seem to provide 10, 25, 50, 100 menu elements. I want to try to grab the current value = 25, so that I can know that there are 25 items in this page. Now you can't get the value without getting this element.